# Is it okay to use a single docker host for multiple things

Tags: docker

As I currently have a private server, which runs docker. Is it okay to have multiple containers running (for example 3 diffrent websites, znc server, some nodejs projects that i had containerized). Or should i run those containers per dockerhost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always it depends on your needs. It seems that you are hosting some private projects conveniently in `docker` containers. It's perfectly fine to run them on a single host. As long as you don't encounter any performance problems I would actually encourage you to stick with it. Because splitting them up means more administrative tasks. Maybe you can use that saved time somewhere else. Don't get me wrong. If you want to dive deeper into container orchestration with for example 
 `Kubernetes` you should actually do it. Because that's the next logical step to production grade hosting with techniques many successful companies use.

**Security Concerns**

File system, process, and memory isolation are core features of `docker`. But there could be *very rare* cases, e.g. the recent meltdown and spectre vulnerabilities, where one container is able to read data from an adjacent one on the same host.

So if you wanted to be completely sure and extremely high data security is your goal, you would need to deploy your containers on different virtual machines. One per instance.

**Performance**

If a container does nothing it won't consume much RAM/CPU/disk I/O at all. I have seen places running up to hundred containers on a single host. This means it actually depends on hardware and your running applications.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, before i dockerized my private server, everything ran on the same machine with the same user. Using docker made it easy for me to migrate a project to another server when a site becomes popular (using docker-compose per project).